# Why is QLocalSocket not ready on connected() with Qt6?

Tags: qt, qt6

I'm currently in the process of updating my application from Qt5 to Qt6 (quite late, I know, I know...).

Doing so, I noticed, that the communication it performs using a `QLocalSocket`, that worked fine before, now randomly fails on the regular.

Debugging the issue, I noticed, that if I write to a `QLocalSocket` right after its considered `connected`, the write fails immediately with a `UnknownSocketError`. `waitForBytesWritten` immediately returns `false`, without touching the timeout the value here is arbitrary.

I can reproduce this problem with the example code below. Compiling with Qt 5.15.2 works perfectly fine every time, compiling with Qt 6.5.3 fails the transmission in roughly 20% of times. It does not make a difference, wether I use `waitForConnected` or the `connected()` signal to determine when to start sending data. Both `isOpen()` and `isWritable()` return `true` before writing.

Adding a `Thread::sleep(10);` before doing the write fixes the issue, and data is sent correctly every time again.

I see this issue on a windows system, compiled with MSVC19.

Is this a known bug I can't seem to find on google, or am I doing something wrong?

---

(I am aware, that the code below isn't the nicest, but it's supposed to be a minimal example that can just be copy pasted without tons of fluff. I'm looking for general issues here).

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalSocket>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

void read(QLocalSocket* client) {
    qDebug() << client->readAll();
    client->disconnectFromServer();
    client->deleteLater();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLocalServer* localServer = new QLocalServer();

    QObject::connect(localServer, &QLocalServer::newConnection, [localServer](){
        while (localServer->hasPendingConnections()) {
            QLocalSocket* client = localServer->nextPendingConnection();

            QObject::connect(client, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, [client]() {
                read(client);
            });

            if (client->bytesAvailable()) {
                read(client);
            }
        }
    });

    localServer->listen("TestSocket");

    auto future = QtConcurrent::run([](){
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            QLocalSocket* localClient = new QLocalSocket();
            QObject::connect(localClient, &QLocalSocket::connected, [localClient](){
                //QThread::msleep(10);
                localClient->write("Hello World");
                if(!localClient->waitForBytesWritten(1000)) {
                    qDebug() << "  " << localClient->errorString();
                }
                localClient->close();
                localClient->deleteLater();
            });
            localClient->connectToServer("TestSocket", QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        }
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that this is a timing issue introduced by Qt6 (not sure why though).  Try increasing the timeout passed to `waitForBytesWritten` or, better still, connect to the `bytesWritten` and various other signals to monitor progress/errors.

Comment: @G.M. - thank you for your input. bytesWritten does indeed do the job. I added an answer with a working example using the signal. The original issue - unfortunately - is still unclear though, so I would be happy for anyone who can provide more insight

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks to G.M.s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536277/why-is-qlocalsocket-not-ready-on-connected-with-qt6?noredirect=1#comment136692749_77536277), here is a working solution. This does still not explain the underlying issue though.*

---

The issue seems to be with the `waitForBytesWritten` function. Connecting to the `bytesWritten` signal, rather than using `waitForBytesWritten` provides the wanted result. Replacing parts of the example above with the code below works perfectly for Qt6 as well as Qt5.

Switching from QtConcurrent to a custom QThread was necessary here, as QtConcurrent would kill the running thread before the slots were executed as the original lambda already exited. This is unrelated to the question though, as using `waitForBytesWritten` will still fail with this structure.

```cpp
int responses = 0;
QThread t2;
t2.start();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    QLocalSocket* localClient = new QLocalSocket();
    localClient->moveToThread(&t2);

    QObject::connect(localClient, &QLocalSocket::bytesWritten, [localClient, &responses](){
        qDebug() << “Responses:” << ++responses;
        localClient->close();
        localClient->deleteLater();
    });

    QObject::connect(localClient, &QLocalSocket::connected, [localClient](){
        localClient->write(“Hello world”);
    });

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(localClient, [localClient](){
        localClient->connectToServer(“TestSocket”, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    });
}
```